# Rsync through java program - issues with remote connection failure

Tags: java, solaris, rsync

I am running rsync through my java application.(Solaris Evn)

The Java application will sync the files with remote machine. During our connection failure testing we noticed an issue running rsync through java program. The java application which is running at source side is not receiving any error message if there are any connection issues during the sync process.

**Brief details about the test scenario:**

1. We run the Java Program
2. The java program starts the rsync command and sync the large number of files from source to remote destination
3. During the sync process we run the `ps -ef | grep rsync` to check whether the processes are running or not at both(source and dest) side. Both side rsync processes are running.
4. We identify the rsync process id at target machine and kill the process with `kill -9 <pid>`
5. The java code didn't receive any error message and didn't exit. It just hung.
6. And also noticed that the rsync process is still running at source side and rsync process is also not printing any log message in the log file.

   Note : If we run the rsync command directly (not through java program) , then everything is working fine. When we stop the rsync process at target the source process will be stopped.

   When RSYNC terminated at target, the Java program and RSYNC is not detecting that the target has issues. No log files written , Java program will hang and becomes unresponsive.

   Through *perl* its working fine. Not sure what the problem with java...!!!

   I don’t have any clues to debug this issue.
   Please share your thoughts and pointer to debug.

Answer (score 1):

In your Java side I recommend creating two additional threads to consume the p.getInputStream() and p.getErrorStream() streams of your Process p.  I think that helps `rsync` feel more loved and cared for.

Something like this (I'm ignoring IOExceptions for simplicity --- you'll have to deal with them!):

```
final Process p = Runtime.exec("rsync"); // however you do this...

Runnable consumeIn = new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    InputStream in = p.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String line;
    while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null ) {
      // Throw away the data?  Or do something with it if you like!
    }
  }
};

Runnable consumeErr = new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    InputStream in = p.getErrorStream();
    // etc... (very similar to consumeIn)
  }
};

new Thread(consumeIn).start();
new Thread(consumeErr).start();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reponse, the thread approach is also didn't work for me. Looks like there is an issue in rsync. If we use rsync compress option (-z) some how its working..the source RSYC is able to detect the error now. ex : rsync -abvrz --delete /source/  /dest/